# Request fails on curl but works on guzzle

Tags: php, curl

Am using the following post  request on guzzle to microsoft graph which works.

```
 $client = new Client([
        'headers' => [ 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token ]
    ]);
     $url = "myurl";
    $response = $client->post(
        $url,
        [
          'body' => json_encode(
            [
                "startDateTime"=>$arr['start_date'],
                "endDateTime"=>$arr['end_date'],
                "meeting"=>$arr['subject']
            ]
        )]
    );
    $payload = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());

     var_dump($payload) //here has data
```

The am doing the same request via curl using

```
    $post = [
        "meeting"=>$arr['subject'],
        "startDateTime"=>$arr['start_date'],
        "endDateTime"=>$arr['end_date'],
    ];
    $authorization = "Authorization: Bearer ".$token; 
    $headers = [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        $authorization
    ];

    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($post));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $error = curl_errno($ch) ? curl_error($ch) : '';

    curl_close($ch);
    if ($error){
        var_dump($error);
        throw new Exception($error,500);
    }
    return $response;
```

But in curl the above in micorsoft graph throws an error Expected not null\r\nParameter name: meeting but the meeting parameter is not empty. I have also tried setting the value of meeting directly via

```
     $post = [
        "meeting"=>"Test meeting",
        "startDateTime"=>$arr['start_date'],
        "endDateTime"=>$arr['end_date'],
    ];
```

But still doesnt solve. I guess it has something to do with body parameter i have set on guzzle which works. How can i resolve this to have it work even on curl

Comment: Doesn't Guzzle use cURL under the hood? BTW, concerning your code, there are PSR guidelines on formatting. Use those, it makes it more likely that people read and understand your code here and are subsequently able to properly analyze it and detect errors.

Comment: Guzzle can be configured to add some default headers or to inject a middleware. So it's possible that there are some other headers that "make the request work" even though your snippet doesn't include them.